# Merging two DataFrames with conditionals to either update column or append row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with identical columns. I want to merge (or join) these dataframes on a key column where if there is a key match between the two, it simply updates a single column of the matching row, else it appends the row the the first/old dataframe.

Example Psudeocode:

```
for row in new_dataset:
if new_dataset['key'] == old_dataset['key']:
    old_dataset['last_seen'] = new_dataset['last_seen']
else:
    append row to old_dataset
```

Example input:

DF1

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data  Data
Bigfoot   2015       2015      Blah  Blah
Loch_Ness 2016       2016      Blah  Blah
UFO       2016       2004      Blah  Blah
```

DF2

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data  Data
UFO       2017       2017      Blah  Blah
Tupac     2017       2017      Blah  Blah
```

Desired Output:

DF3

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data  Data
Bigfoot   2015       2015      Blah  Blah
Loch_Ness 2016       2016      Blah  Blah
UFO       2016       2017      Blah  Blah
Tupac     2017       2017      Blah  Blah
```

edit: I've tried several approaches, to include: join with key as index, doing a merge right on key with explicit calls to the column and then merging left to append the non-matched values. The issues I am facing is that the merges either want to merge all columns, and creates a completely duplicated df or when I explicitly call a column, it doesn't allow to match a pandas series aganst a dataframe. When I normalize to using 2 series on a column call I have no way of returning back the specific rows which matched to merge on, etc.

Comment: `pd.concat` then `drop_duplicate`

Comment: That doesn't update the first_seen and last_seen columns appropriately, and there will be data loss

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @itotallyforgot .  It will likely be helpful to those looking to provide you an answer to know what you have already tried, and how it did not work properly.

Comment: @Degan I've updated it with a few of the things I've tried.

Comment: `@Wen was correct!` Almost... not quite... `UFO` needs `2016    2017` in its rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer**

```
df1.append(df2).pipe(
    lambda d: (
        lambda f: f('Key').assign(
            Last_Seen=f('Key', 'last').Last_Seen.values)
    )(d.drop_duplicates)
).reset_index(drop=True)

         Key  First_Seen  Last_Seen  Data Data.1
0    Bigfoot        2015       2015  Blah   Blah
1  Loch_Ness        2016       2016  Blah   Blah
2        UFO        2016       2017  Blah   Blah
3      Tupac        2017       2017  Blah   Blah
```

**Variant**
Less `lambda` more `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, 'outer', 'Key', suffixes=['', '_']).pipe(
    lambda d: d.fillna(
        d.filter(regex='_$').rename(columns=lambda x: x[:-1])
    ).assign(Last_Seen=d.Last_Seen_.fillna(d.Last_Seen))
)[df1.columns].astype(df1.dtypes)

         Key  First_Seen  Last_Seen  Data Data.1
0    Bigfoot        2015       2015  Blah   Blah
1  Loch_Ness        2016       2016  Blah   Blah
2        UFO        2016       2017  Blah   Blah
3      Tupac        2017       2017  Blah   Blah
```

---

**Old Answer**

```
d1, d2 = df1.set_index('Key').align(df2.set_index('Key'))
d3 = d1.combine_first(d2)
d3.update(d2.Last_Seen)
d3 = d3.reset_index().astype(df1.dtypes)
d3

         Key  First_Seen  Last_Seen  Data Data.1
0    Bigfoot        2015       2015  Blah   Blah
1  Loch_Ness        2016       2016  Blah   Blah
2      Tupac        2017       2017  Blah   Blah
3        UFO        2016       2017  Blah   Blah
```

Comment: That's it. Ideally I wouldn't want to create a 3rd dataframe as the first 2 will already rather be rather large on their own, but I've tested it a few times and it looks to work beautifully. Thank you! I can see now as well where I messed it up when I tried to use combine_first as well.

Comment: If you're interested, I've provided a different answer.

Comment: I'll do some comparison testing with the larger datasets and let you know how they perform

Comment: I did some testing, and the basic gist of it is that counter intuitively your 3rd answer that just creates a 3rd dataframe in memory to work with was both faster and less memory intensive. I Although it was fun redlining 64gbs of memory with the variant, haha!

There's probably a good bit of optimization I could do to get the memory issues under control, but I'm just not there yet skill-wise. I still want to play with it so I can understand exactly what's happening with that. In the meantime, thank you again for your help!